# ¿Cómo guardar un array de JSON en un schema mongoose?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose

tengo el siguiente schema en el que trato de hacer un array de productos (Ya existe el modelo)

```
proveedorFacturaSchema: new Schema({
    id_negocio: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'negocio' },
    categoria:String,
    nombre: String,
    productos: [{
        id_producto: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'producto' },
        compra: Number,
        cantidad: Number
    }]
})
```

Necesito saber cómo debo enviar la información vía **POST** para llenar ese array de productos, cuando envío el **JSON** con los datos no los guarda por más que lleguen al servidor

Lo intento de esta forma:

```
let facturaProvedor = new proveedorFactura({
                            id_negocio: res.locals.negocio.id,
                            nombre: req.body.nombre,
                            categoria: req.body.categoria,
                            productos :  req.body.productos
                        });
    facturaProvedor.save(function (err) {
                            if (!err){
                                    console.log("factura guardado exito");
                                    console.log(facturaProvedor);
                                    res.send('factura agregado')
                            }else {
                                console.log("Ha ocurrido un error",err);
                                res.send("error")                               }
                        });
```

req.body.productos = {id_producto: "5936460d2fabd233f0ddaca3", compra: 3, cantidad:2}

Lo que llega por POST es `req.body.productos = {id_producto: "5936460d2fabd233f0ddaca3", compra: 3, cantidad:2}`

Agradezco cualquier ayuda o tutorial que se relacione con este tema.

EDITADO:

Me aparece también un error "Cast to Array failed", entonces decidí poner el json directamente en el código y funcionó.

```
let facturaProvedor = new proveedorFactura({
                            id_negocio: res.locals.negocio.id,
                            nombre: req.body.nombre,
                            categoria: req.body.categoria,
                            productos : [{id_producto: "5936460d2fabd233f0ddaca3", compra: 3, cantidad:2},{id_producto: "5936460d2fabd233f0ddaca3", compra: 3, cantidad:2}]
                        });
```

La pregunta ahora es cómo hacer que al enviar por POST llegue ese array que se ve arriba?

Answer (score 3):

productos dentro de proveedorFacturaSchema es un Schema tambien, de modo que se tiene que declarar tal que así:

```js
// creas esquema de productos
const productSchema = new Schema({
      id_producto: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'producto' },
      compra: Number,
      cantidad: Number
});

proveedorFacturaSchema: new Schema({
    id_negocio: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'negocio' },
    categoria:String,
    nombre: String,
    
    // defines el campo productos como un productSchema 
    productos: [productSchema]
});
```